# how to put the result of an echo command into an ansible variable

Tags: ansible

I have $MY_VAR set to some value on the remote host, and I want to query it from a playbook
(put it's value in an ansible variable), here's what I am seeing :

```
   - name: put shell var into ansible var
     command: echo $MY_VAR
     register: my_var

   - debug: var=my_var
```

```
ok: [192.168.78.10] => {
    "my_var": {
        "changed": true, 
        "cmd": [
            "echo", 
            "$my_var"
        ], 
        "delta": "0:00:00.002284", 
        "end": "2014-12-17 18:10:01.097217", 
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": "echo $my_var", 
            "module_name": "command"
        }, 
        "rc": 0, 
        "start": "2014-12-17 18:10:01.094933", 
        "stderr": "", 
        "stdout": "$my_var", 
        "stdout_lines": [
            "$my_var"
        ]
    }
}
```

### note:

If I change the command to :

```
 command: pwd
```

then I get the expected result :

```
"my_var": {
  "stdout": "/home/vagrant", 
  "stdout_lines": [
      "/home/vagrant"  
  ]
}
```

It seems as if echo does not expand when called from ansible

Comment: Are you sure, this environment variable is accessible anytime you ssh to the remote host? If you ssh to the machine, does doing "echo $MY_VAR" print something? I mean env variables could be set per terminal instance, so is it possible that your env variable is set on one terminal, but if you start a new tab it might not be visible?

Comment: echo $MY_VAR on the remote host prints the expected value, it is set in the ~/.profile of the user

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you are using the `command` module. [Here's what the documentation says](http://docs.ansible.com/command_module.html):

> The given command will be executed on all selected nodes. It will not
>   be processed through the shell, so variables like `$HOME` and operations
>   like "<", ">", "|", and "&" will not work (use the `shell` module if you
>   need these features).

So, use `shell` instead of `command`.

Comment: Doesn't lookup run locally? "These plugins are evaluated on the Ansible control machine"

Comment: Its also worth noting that environment variables may not be loaded at all - Ansible doesn't connect with an interactive session, so .bash_profile for example will not be parsed when Ansible connects to the server, and any configuration on the remote server held in there will be ignored...

Comment: @keba I agree, the whole thing is a **big red flag**. It seems like flagrant abuse of Ansible and configuration management.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do what you want to do, but without echo. Note you have to use braces to de-reference the variable.

```
- name: put shell var into ansible var
  set_fact:
    my_var: "{{ lookup('env','MY_VAR') }}"
- name: print var
  debug: 
    msg: var={{ my_var }}
```